# ‘LIBs NOT FOUND’ Error in building Assimp with MinGW in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, assimp

I'm learning OpenGL with the tutorial of https://learnopengl.com/. And I need to build Assimp in cmake-gui. I'm new to Cmake and never used it before. I met some confusing Errors, it seems like I miss some essential libs or cmake can't find root of libs.

My environment is MinGW v8.1.0, cmake v3.19.2, Assimp v4.1.0, Windows10

I get this message:

```
Shared libraries enabled
Looking for DirectX...
DirectX_PREFIX_PATH changed.
Found DirectX: F:/dxsdk/Lib/x86/d3d9.lib
DX lib dir: F:/dxsdk/Lib/x86
Looking for ZLIB...
Checking for module 'zzip-zlib-config'
  No package 'zzip-zlib-config' found
Could not locate ZLIB
compiling zlib from souces
CMake Deprecation Warning at contrib/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:1 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Deprecation Warning at contrib/zlib/CMakeLists.txt:8 (cmake_policy):
  The OLD behavior for policy CMP0048 will be removed from a future version
  of CMake.

  The cmake-policies(7) manual explains that the OLD behaviors of all
  policies are deprecated and that a policy should be set to OLD only under
  specific short-term circumstances.  Projects should be ported to the NEW
  behavior and not rely on setting a policy to OLD.


Checking for module 'minizip'
  No package 'minizip' found
CMake Deprecation Warning at code/CMakeLists.txt:46 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Warning (dev) at F:/cmake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:426 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (rt) does
  not match the name of the calling package (RT).  This can lead to problems
  in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables (e.g.,
  `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake-modules/FindRT.cmake:19 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  code/CMakeLists.txt:807 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Could NOT find rt (missing: RT_LIBRARY) 
INFO RT-extension not found. glTF import/export will be built without Open3DGC-compression.
Enabled formats: AMF 3DS AC ASE ASSBIN ASSXML B3D BVH COLLADA DXF CSM HMP IRRMESH IRR LWO LWS MD2 MD3 MD5 MDC MDL NFF NDO OFF OBJ OGRE OPENGEX PLY MS3D COB BLEND IFC XGL FBX Q3D Q3BSP RAW SIB SMD STL TERRAGEN 3D X X3D GLTF 3MF MMD
Disabled formats:
CMake Deprecation Warning at tools/assimp_view/CMakeLists.txt:39 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


Looking for DirectX...
DirectX_PREFIX_PATH changed.
DX lib dir: F:/dxsdk/Lib/x86
CMake Deprecation Warning at tools/assimp_cmd/CMakeLists.txt:39 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


CMake Warning (dev) at F:/cmake/share/cmake-3.19/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:426 (message):
  The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (IL) does
  not match the name of the calling package (DevIL).  This can lead to
  problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables
  (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake-modules/FindDevIL.cmake:71 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:421 (FIND_PACKAGE)
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

Could NOT find IL (missing: IL_LIBRARIES IL_INCLUDE_DIR) 
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:439 (MESSAGE):
  Build of assimp_qt_viewer is disabled.  Unsatisfied dendencies: Qt5 DevIL


CMake Deprecation Warning at test/CMakeLists.txt:39 (cmake_minimum_required):
  Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
  CMake.

  Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
  CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


Configuring done
```

I installed ZLIB and pointed ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR but it seems like more libs about ZLIB are required. Do I need to install the libs one by one?

Answer (score 0):

All the issues shown in your posts are CMake-warnings which shall indicate, that:

- Your CMake minimal version requested by the libraries are outdated.
- Some libraries can't be located on your devbox, so the internal version from assimp will be used.

So from my point of view your build shall run. To get rid of those warnings you can just update to the latest master of assimp or just use version 5.0.1 from [here](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/releases/tag/v5.0.1)